# CheckBox status save to database Android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I'm going to save the checkbox status when back press. It will show update status on next time. whatever it's checked or unchecked, it will save to database when user click back press. How can i do for this? Do you have any idea?

I have two activity. MainActivity and TaskActivity(2 Checkbox).

Comment: when you check/uncheck,you will get  it's value in checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener and then save it's status into a database... what's the issue with this??

Comment: You can use shared preferences also

Comment: What did you try for this? You would need to do: 1. get status of checkbox. 2. Save in database or Shared Preference - TRUE / FALSE. 3. Next time, retrieve status. 4. Check the checkbox if TRUE

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping me.I'm trying to do the task is do or not do. if do, user will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first on backpress use this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();


    if(checkBox.isChecked())
    {
        // save its status(true)to Database or using SharedPreferences
    }
    else
    {
        // save its status(false)to Database or using SharedPreferences
    }

}
```

after that in onCreate use that code:

```
    boolean check =  // get here value from Database or SharedPreferences;
    if(check)
    {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```